# Blue Pelican Java Lesson 26 Project Gymnastics

Tags: java

> Use your new BaseClass class to implement the following project. Call
>   the new class Gym:
>
> Ten people are judging an international gymnastics competition. Each
>   judge gives a contestant a performance score between 0.0 and 10.0,
>   inclusive, with the score given to one decimal place. Since some
>   judges favor their own country’s competitors and/or give lower scores
>   than deserved to their country’s rivals, the highest and lowest scores
>   are discarded before averaging the eight other scores. Write a program
>   that will read in the judges’ ten scores, discard the highest and
>   lowest score, and compute the average of the eight other scores to
>   four decimal places.
>
> **Input**
>
> Read in one or more data sets (assume you don’t know ahead of time how
>   many) of 10 scores from the file DataGym.in. Each data set will use
>   exactly one line of the input text file. There will be ten floating
>   point numbers (each separated from the others by spaces) between 0.0
>   and 10.0, inclusive (to one decimal place) on each line of the file.
>
> Input file:
>
> 8.7 6.5 0.1 3.2 5.7 9.9 8.3 6.5 6.5 1.5
>
> 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
>
> 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
>
> **Output**
>
> Print, for each data set that is input, the average to four decimal
>   places. This average should be preceded each time by “For Competitor
>   X, the average score is ”, where X denotes the competitor’s position (starting with 1) in the input file.
>
> Output to screen for above input file:
>
> For Competitor #1, the average is 5.8625
>
> For Competitor #2, the average is 0.0000
>
> For Competitor #3, the average is 1.0000

My code so far:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Gym {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        fmt.setMinimumFractionDigits(4);
        fmt.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);

        Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("C:\\temp_Name\\DataGym.in.txt"));
        int maxIndx = -1;
        String text[] = new String[1000];
        while (sf.hasNext()) {
            maxIndx++;
            text[maxIndx] = sf.nextLine();
        }

        sf.close();

        for (int j = 0; j <= maxIndx; j++) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(text[j]);
            double a = 0;
            double array[] = new double[1000];
            double scoreAverage = 0;
            int contestant = 0;
            if (j <= 10) {
                a = sc.nextDouble();
                array[j] += a;
            } else {
                Arrays.sort(array);
                int i = 0;
                while (i < 10) {
                    scoreAverage += array[i];
                    i++;
                }
            }
            contestant++;
            String s = fmt.format(scoreAverage);
            double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
            System.out.println("For Competitor #" + contestant + ", the average is " + d);
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting this:

> For Competitor #1, the average is 0.0
>
> For Competitor #1, the average is 0.0
>
> For Competitor #1, the average is 0.0

How would I discard the highest and lowest scores?

Comment: You reinitialize your `contestant` variable (as `0`) **inside** the loop on each iteration..

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `int Contestant = 0;` outside of the loop. This way it does not reset to 0 every time you go through the loop.

Also move `Double sumAverage = 0;` outside of the loop.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but for me t won't print out the average for any of them